# Installed WebCamStudio doesn't open in my ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: installation

First I have installed Webcam Studio using `webcamstudio_0.56-1~getdeb2_all.deb` with software center. It was installed without error messages. But couldn't run /open with double-click the Dash Home icon. Then I uninstalled it,and cleaned the computer with Tweaks. Then again installed using Terminal, with following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/multimedia
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install webcamstudio
```

There was a message warning that -e should have -E or -F. But however it was installed. Still I cannot open it with Double-click the Dash Home icon.
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: try something easy like cheese software or guvcview or kamera software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed it successfully with this;

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webcamstudio/webcamstudio-dailybuilds/ubuntu precise main"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install webcamstudio
```